# what is the exact meaning of "how long are you staying in London"

Tags: progressive-aspect

If I say "how long are you staying in London?" , does it always mean that my stay in London  has begun  or can I use it if my stay begins in two weeks for example and that I have already booked my hotel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be used in non-past situations, either of someone who has already arrived in London, or someone who is planning to travel there.

This is the "future plan" sense of the present continuous.

Answer (score 0):

You could already be in London, or you could be planning to go to London, as James says in his answer. The question means "How long do you intend to stay | remain in London?"

It is about intention, and only by context can you know whether it means "now that you are here" or "when you get there".